# Incorrect count while reading csv file using spark with multiline true option

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, spark-csv

I am facing issue while reading the csv file using spark with multiline option as true. Is there any criteria when we should set multiline as true or false?

Using windows 10, scala 2.11.11 and spark 2.2.0 version.

**Dataset that I am using to test against:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15k7ffbyQZ8h_93t4G5Y1U2rPHSAyA9GX/view?usp=sharing

```
val df = sparkSession.read.format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", true)
      .option("delimiter", ",")
      .option("multiLine", true)
      .option("wholeFile", true)
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace","true")
      .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace","true")
      .option("encoding","utf-8")
      .option("quote","\"")
      .option("escape","\"")
      .load("C:/Notebook/work/input/Country.csv").repartition(2)
```

With multiline option as true, I get the count as 77.
If I set the multiline option to false, I get correct count - 247

Can someone please let me know what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, `multiline` was made for cases when one record was splitted across many lines. Which, is clearly not your case. Thus, why using it?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez: i am getting a dataset from multiple sources and upfront I am not aware whether I should be setting multiline to true or false. Some of the data has multiline and some dont. hence, the ask.

Comment: In addition, if the data doesn't have new line in the column, multiline shouldnt lead to issues. Isn't it. For a small dataset of 5 rows split into 2 partitions, I am not seeing this issue.

Comment: This seems to work for me: `val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("sep", ",").option("encoding", "utf-8").option("quote", "\"").option("multiLine", "true").csv("file:///home/balmungsan/Country.csv").repartition(2)` using **Spark** _2.4.0_ with **Scala** _2.12.8_ - With work, I mean that the _count_ returned `247`.

Comment: Sorry to mention - I am using scala 2.11.11 and spark 2.2.0 on windows 10. I don't see any difference in the code as such. Commented the extra attributes to make it similar to yours and still doesn't work. Does that mean it's a bug in Spark 2.2.0?

Comment: Just tested it with **Spark** `2.2.0` and **Scala** `2.11.11`, it worked. Maybe the only difference is me using **Linux** instead of **Windows**?

Comment: Thats really strange.